# Unlock gnome-keyring from a temp dbus session

Tags: python, subprocess, dbus, python-keyring, gnome-keyring-daemon

I'm trying to write a **python** application that can unlock `gnome-keyring` from a text-only system (headless machine) and retrieve the credentials. I have the `gnome-keyring` package installed in this machine.

Basically, my application will:

1. Start a new dbus session
2. Unlock the gnome-keyring in that dbus session
3. Extract the credentials from the keyring
4. Destroy the dbus session bus

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://pypi.org/project/keyring/#using-keyring-on-headless-linux-systems

I tried reading: [Python DBUS SESSION_BUS - X11 dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143785/python-dbus-session-bus-x11-dependency) but, the OP uses `dbus-launch` instead of the `dbus-run-session`. The original man page for `dbus-launch` says to use 'dbus-run-session` for text-only systems.

If I start a new dbus session using python's subprocess, how can I run the step #2 in the same dbus-session?

Comment: I think this newer answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962998/how-do-i-read-store-a-password-in-a-possibly-locked-gnome-keyring-manager-from-t/77962999#77962999

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to spawn a second program in your project beneath `dbus-run-session`, or you will need to use something other than `dbus-run-session` to run your own session bus. `dbus-run-session` is designed to run a single program in its own bus; once that program terminates, the bus is shut down. So either you need to provide a second program which does steps 2 and 3 from your plan, or you need to more explicitly set up and tear down your own `dbus-daemon` instance from your top-level program, replicating some of the behaviour of `dbus-run-session`.

Typically this would involve:

- Providing a `dbus-daemon` configuration file to use.
- Running `dbus-daemon --config-file=path/to/config --address=path/to/socket --nofork`.
- Setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path/to/socket` in your program’s environment before doing anything with the keyring.
- Doing whatever you need to with the keyring.
- Terminating the `dbus-daemon` subprocess.